# How to install Robot Operating System ROSJava on Windows?

Tags: java, maven, compiler-construction, gradle, ros

**The documentation for ROS is terrible.**

One great irony is that the Groovy and ROSJava versions of ROS was created to allow developers on platforms like Windows to utilize the great robotics SDK, while all the installation instructions are still geared toward linux/ubuntu users.

The [ROSJava core](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava_core) documentation says:

```
TODO: write a guide for a strictly java installation.
```

I've tried to follow the instructions [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html) on the Google Code project, but seeing as all the instructions assume I'm running Ubuntu, it is very difficult as a traditional Windows/Web developer to translate into windows instructions on my own.

The link is also broken to the GIT repo, it is moved to github: https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core.git

If you were looking for **rosws documentation**, its here. Another broken link: http://www.ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosinstall/html/

Now, wanting a versatile IDE for coding, I chose Eclipse because it can handle Python, Java and c++. Now I have no idea how to build this project with Gradle and Maven-- Heck, I'm not even sure I should be building it.

**Is there a definitive installation/build tutorial for ROSJava on Windows?** If not, I think it would greatly benefit the community if somebody could create a walk-through that can help developers make their first "Hello World" in robotics.  I've done some processing and some light Java before, but nothing too serious. The manual should assume you are new to Java, ROS and all the dependencies/build helpers/compilers. I feel like  all the instructions from [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/) and [ROSWiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/) assume you're familiar with many tools and dependencies or are aware of the historical context of ROSJava versus Groovy versus Linux implementations. Many of the necessary tools are off the beaten path for a C#.NET, Objective C or Javascript/Web developer.

Also, a big detriment is that **the pre-compiled version of the ROS SDK is outright missing from ROSWiki.** "Page Does Not Exist" so, us newcomers have to also install 10-16 dependencies for compiling the core (not to mention figuring out how to configure and use them).

Additionally, build scripts named in the Wiki don't even exist yet.

Currently, I've not even gotten far enough to start encountering problems like this: [Gradle Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483924/gradle-eclipse-plugin)

Comment: you can try my instructions on how to get ros running on windows.. https://github.com/ipa-fxm-db/windows_ros-groovy

Comment: @FalvorScape did you try that guide ? now three years later...Is there still no guide to install RosJava for Indigo on Windows ?

Comment: no idea. I changed industries and abandoned this.

Comment: thanks for the reply anyways ! good luck with your new stuff

Answer (score 0):

While the ROS documentation has improved in general during the past years, the ROS Java documentation is even currently not as detailed.

Using ROS_JAVA is in fact as easy as using any other dependency if you do not use custom messages.
ROS_JAVA can be practically divided in two parts.

1. An API to create your own servers/clients and publishers/subscribers
2. A pure Java roscore

The API is perfect for accessing and consuming ROS based services/topics/actions written in any language.
The pure Java roscore can be used for testing, or installation in any system that runs Java, in cases where the C++ ROS is not supported. However it is not as complete as ROS C++.

If you do **not** use custom messages you can easily add the required dependencies.
The following configuration should work in gradle.

```
repositories {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
         maven {
            url "https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:[0.3,0.4)'

    implementation 'org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:message_generation:0.3.3'
    implementation 'org.ros.rosjava_messages:std_msgs:0.5.11'
}
```

This is part of a simple "Hello World" pure Java project that I have published [here](http://%20https://github.com/SpyrosKou/Plain-ROS-Java-System-Example).
For programming only in Java /ROS Java [you do not need to install ROSjava in windows](https://spyroskoukas.com/2020/05/15/how-to-setup-a-ros-java-system-in-windows/). (This is also an article I had written trying to provide some quick instructions on the issue.)
If you also need to compile messages without a ROS installation then you can also do this manually through java.

Finally it is worth noting that [ROS Noetic can be installed in windows](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Windows). While this is not a requirement for development using ROS java.